# How to display a link on top of an image on mouseover while also lowering the opacity of the image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image of width: 1260, height: 709. 
I want to set opacity to 0.4 AND a clickable link to appear in the centre of the image on hover, preferably only when the user hovers over the centre of the image (pixel co-ordinates 420, 230, 850, 510). 
I can create an overlay to satisfy the opacity. And using map I can get the co-ordinates to link to another page. But I can't see how to get both conditions satisfied at the same time. To be as clear as I can, I want the image co-ordinates (or just the centre of the image in general) to link with a text that appears on hover while the opacity of the image as a whole is also down at 0.4. Here's my work so far.

HTML

```
<div class="image-container fade" data-text="Shop Processors">
            <img src="images/shop/cpu.png" alt="" usemap="#processorMap">
            <map name="processorMap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="420, 230, 850, 510" href="index.html" alt="">
            </map>
</div>
```

CSS

```
main {
    text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  height: 709px;
  width: 1260px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.fade::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.fade:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, and is a simpler approach at the same time.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
}

.image,
.link-container {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.link-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
}

.image-container:hover .link-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container fade">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/240/160" alt="">
  <div class="link-container">
    <a class="link" href="#">Shop Processors</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

We put a `.link-container` on top of the image with `opacity: 0` and `position: absolute` and stretch it to all sides so it covers the whole image.

Then inside that container we include our link. The container has `display: flex` and two properties which center the link horizontally and vertically inside of it.

Lastly we add transitions to both the link-container and to the image, and trigger both opacities with `.image-container:hover`

Comment: I just needed to add a margin to the image-container and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @BenLawlor Great! Glad I could help